# "WOULD" in the same clause as "IF"

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would

I heard this sentence and I thought if it was possible that 'would" could be in the same clause as 'if', I mean I've read that it's possible if 'would' conveys "willingness?" But in this example I don't see the case.

> I don't know if it'd be that worth it.

What's the explanation for this?

Comment: Please note that the "if" in your sentence doesn't express a condition.  It isn't part of an "if...[then]..." conditional.  Rather, it is a synonym for "whether" = "I don't know whether it would be worth it [or not]".

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't convey willingness, it describes a hypothetical situation.

> [If we paid £10k for that old car,] I don't know if it would be worth it.